# Поиск слова в словаре

Tags: java, массивы, map

У меня есть большой текст и словарь на ~100 000 слов. Нужно найти в этом тексте все слова с помощью словаря и посчитать их встречаемость.

Я cделал так:

1) Разбил весь текст на слова, записав их в `ArrayList`.

2) Словарь записал в `HashMap`, ключ - слово, значение - различные окончания.

Это все делается довольно быстро. А потом я cделал поиск слов из `HashMap`-а в `ArrayList`-е, результат записываю в еще один `HashMap`, и это делается очень очень долго.

Сравниваю я так:

```
Set<String> key = Dictionary.map.keySet();
Map mapWords = new HashMap<>();

for (String word : arrayList) {
    String strMax = "";
    boolean flag = true;
    for (String dicword : keyMap) {
        if (word.toLowerCase().indexOf(dicword) != -1) {//Проверка слова
            if (strMax.length() < dicword.length()) {
                strMax = dicword;
            }
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    //Подсчет вхождений слов
    if (flag) {
        flag = true;
        mapWords.put(word, new mapValue(0, "?"));
    } else {
        if (mapWords.containsKey(strMax)) {//Проверка на наличие ключа
            number = mapWords.get(strMax).getNumber();
            number++;
            mapWords.put(strMax, new mapValue(number, Dictionary.map.get(strMax).get(0)));
        } else {
            number = 1;
            mapWords.put(strMax, new mapValue(number, Dictionary.map.get(strMax).get(0)));
        }
    }
}
```

Я думаю, что надо начинать перебирать словарь с наиболее больших слов, которые похожи на искомое, но как это сделать не представляю.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Мне кажется хранить нужно в бинарном дереве. И искать по нему. Нужно подумать как это изящно сделать.

Answer (score 1):

ну правильно у вас со скоростью проблемы. :))

вы ~100 000 раз проходите один и тот же массив, зачем?
вы сделайте так:

храним:

- set(множество) - ваш словарь (не знаю
     что лучше хэш или суффиксное дерево... )
- map (ключ(string)->значение(int)) - найденное слово и количество повторов

алгоритм:

1. разбиваем текст на токены
2. проходим массив токенов, один раз
       ищем каждый токен в словаре, если
       нашли инкрементируем значение в мапе

в итоге сложность будет гораздо меньше чем в вашем алгоритме, да ещё и распараллелить можно...